# Бот реагирует на команды со всех чатов в которых он есть, telebot

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot, python-telegram-bot

Сделал бота на PyTellegrambotAPI, он ставит реакцию на каждое сообщение, бота можно выключать/включать, но когда я выключаю его в одном чате, он выключается во всех

```
import telebot
from telebot import types
import time
global pause
pause = True
bot = telebot.TeleBot('...')
CONTENT_TYPES = ["text", "audio", "document", "photo", "sticker", "video", "video_note", "voice", "location", "contact",
                 "new_chat_members", "left_chat_member", "new_chat_title", "new_chat_photo", "delete_chat_photo",
                 "group_chat_created", "supergroup_chat_created", "channel_chat_created", "migrate_to_chat_id",
                 "migrate_from_chat_id", "pinned_message"]
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def lol(message):
    print(message.text, ' test')
    print('lol')
    if pause == False and message.text != '/stop':
        print('lol if')
        bot.set_message_reaction(message.chat.id, message.message_id, [types.ReactionTypeEmoji('')])
    else:
        if message.text == '/start':
            print('lol else start stop in')
            start(message)
            return
        elif message.text == '/stop':
            print('lol else start stop in')
            start(message)
            return
        else:
            print('not in')
            pass
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start', 'stop'])
def start(message):
    print('start')
    if message.text == '/start':
        global pause
        pause = False
        print('start if pause false')
        print(pause)
    elif message.text == '/stop':
        pause = True
        print('start if pause true')
        print(pause)
        return
    else:
        print('start else')
        pass

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

В объекте message есть вся информация: из какого чата (канала или личных сообщений) и от какого пользователя пришло сообщение. Надо лишь отсеять ненужные.